# Why does these 2 components have the same behavior if i am instantiating them 2 times differently?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, controlsfx

Here is the declaration:

```
@FXML
private CustomTextField txtFieldUsuario;

@FXML
private CustomPasswordField txtFieldPassword;
```

And here is the initialization:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    new TextFieldUtil(txtFieldUsuario).clearable();

    new PasswordFieldUtil(txtFieldPassword).clearable();

    adminLogin();

    imageView.setImage(new Image("/foto/logo_fix.png"));

    Icono.agregarImagenBoton(btnIniciarSesion, Icono.INICIAR_SESION);

    enterKeyPressed();
}
```

Here is the TextFieldUtil class:

```
public class TextFieldUtil extends CustomTextField{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    private CustomTextField[] textFields;

    public TextFieldUtil(CustomTextField... textFields) {
        this.textFields = textFields;
    }

    public void propiedades() {

    }

    public void clearable() {
        for (CustomTextField customTextField : textFields) {
            customTextField.setRight(Icono.BORRAR_TEXTFIELDS);

            customTextField.getRight().autosize();

            customTextField.getRight().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

            customTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (customTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {

                    customTextField.getRight().setVisible(false);

                } else {

                    customTextField.getRight().setVisible(true);

                    customTextField.getRight().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
                        if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && !customTextField.getText().isEmpty() && customTextField.getRight().isVisible()) {
                            customTextField.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void mascara(TextFieldMascara textFieldMascara) {
        switch (textFieldMascara) {
            case TELEFONO:
                break;
            case RNC:
                break;
            case PRECIO:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the PasswordUtil class:

```
public class PasswordFieldUtil extends CustomPasswordField{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    private CustomPasswordField[] passwordFields;

    public PasswordFieldUtil(CustomPasswordField... passwordFields) {
        this.passwordFields = passwordFields;
    }

    public void propiedades() {

    }

    public void clearable() {
        for (CustomPasswordField customPasswordField : passwordFields) {
            customPasswordField.setRight(Icono.BORRAR_TEXTFIELDS);

            customPasswordField.getRight().autosize();

            customPasswordField.getRight().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

            customPasswordField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (customPasswordField.getText().isEmpty()) {

                    customPasswordField.getRight().setVisible(false);

                } else {

                    customPasswordField.getRight().setVisible(true);

                    customPasswordField.getRight().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
                        if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && !customPasswordField.getText().isEmpty() && customPasswordField.getRight().isVisible()) {

                            customPasswordField.setText("");

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the image with the result, containing the image only the second component. And when I click it in the second the component, the component that gets erased its the first one (CustomTextField).

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQt1p.png)

If someone could tell me why this is happening I would appreciate it in advance.

Comment: `new TextFieldUtil(txtFieldUsuario).clearable();` - where do you assign this anywhere?

Comment: I'm assigning it on the same variable, that's why its void. I have one for combobox and other for spinner, they both work well and without problem. The problem is with these 2. @EJoshuaS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting same `Node` instance in a scene graph in this code. Because of that, event filters for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` is set to same icon.

```
customTextField.setRight(Icono.BORRAR_TEXTFIELDS);

customPasswordField.setRight(Icono.BORRAR_TEXTFIELDS);
```

Try to change the code for example:

```
customTextField.setRight(new ImageView( yourImage ));

customPasswordField.setRight(new ImageView( yourImage ));
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks man. I appreciate it. I didn't know it was gonna behave like that. Thank you man. Thank you!